# Cannot display the images in fronted React. The field is blank

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to display the images from django in React but the image field is blank. The content and title however is displayed. What could be the problem? Below is the code:

```
const GetPostData = () => {
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
// const classes = useStyles();
useEffect(() => {
   fetchData();
 }, []);

const config = {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: `JWT ${localStorage.getItem("access")}`,
    Accept: "application/json",
  },
};

const fetchData = () => {
  axios
    .get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/list/ListView/`, config)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      setData(res.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};

return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <div className="item-container">
      {data.map((item, index) => (
          <div className="card" key={index}>
          <img src={item.image} alt=""/>
          <h3>{item.title}</h3>
          <p>{item.content}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  </React.Fragment>
);
};

export default GetPostData;
```

Comment: what are you trying to put in img src? is it base64? is it a url?

Comment: The image source is a url

Comment: If the image src is a url how do I access the image?

Comment: actually if the item.image you get from server is a url, what you are doing should work. maybe item.image is empty, maybe the sent url is broken. you should log your res.data to see the data, and look in to console if there is a error.

Comment: There is no error. When I log my res.data , everything looks fine. I get the following: (image "http://localhost:8000/media/images/rl.png").

Comment: I have realized when I log res.data.image, I get the image url. Onclicking it, the field is blank, what could be the problem here?